# How do I interpret the output of dd when the option status=progress is chosen?

Tags: dd, coreutils

The `dd` [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) is very limited on this:
`

```
status=LEVEL
              The LEVEL of information to print to stderr; 'none' suppresses
              everything but error messages, 'noxfer' suppresses the final
              transfer statistics, 'progress' shows periodic transfer
              statistics
```

This does not say anything about the actual output, which looks something like this when I copy a large image file, e.g.:
`dd if=input.img of=output.img status=progress`

results in:

[image]

The transfer speed and the copying time so far is obvious, but what do the first three numbers mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first number (1207841280) is the number of bytes copied so far. The second number is this interpreted as the SI unit Gigabytes (1 GB is 1000<sup>3</sup> bytes). The third number is this interpreted as the IEC unit [Gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) (1 GiB is 1024<sup>3</sup> bytes). Notice the difference between "GB" and "GiB".

The source code of the `dd` command in the GNU coreutils package uses variables called `si` and `iec` to hold the last two of these numbers.  See [the `print_xfer_stats` function in `dd.c`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/900b5621e685df7ffd001fc64bc9d44b06b13900/src/dd.c#L765).  The actual output happens on line 821.

Comment: Oh okay, I totally missed the units.

Comment: @JanM. I did too. I didn't see them until after I had it figured out _from the source_!

Comment: I landed here because I was looking for the _transfer speed_ measurement unit (SI vs. IEC) and was too lazy to dig through the source code. As it turns out, the transfer speed is measured in SI units. This is also consistent with the notation in the dd output, as IEC units have an extra 'i' between the multiplier and the unit (the 'B'). Note that there's no 'i' in the transfer speed units. Thanks @Kusalananda for the excellent answer and for pointing out the exact source code file.